# Defining a tail recursive function equivalent to this Haskell function

Tags: haskell, recursion, tail-recursion

I am struggling with a problem from a previous exam regarding tail recursion. 
The problem is to define a tail recursive function `duh`, that is equivalent to the function below.

```
dup [] = ([], [])
dup (x:xs) = let (as, bs) = dup xs in (x:as, x:bs)
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to approach this problem? I am only semi familiar with the concept of tail recursion, so any further explanations would be very welcome

Comment: The transformation they want you to do seems counterproductive, see https://wiki.haskell.org/Tail_recursion.

Comment: @Gurkenglas Exam problems aren't always of practical concern.

Comment: From a homework perspective, @chepner's answer addresses how you generally come up with tail-recursive functions in strict languages, and @WillNess'es answer evades the need for any recursion in this particular problem, since you don't need to recursively deep-copy immutable values, you can just refer to the value twice. Using `Control.Arrow` you can also write that as `dup = id &&& id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, you use an accumulator to build up your result as you go. In this case, you want to accumulate each element of the input into a *pair* of lists. This pair of lists gets passed from one call to the other. Once you reach your base case, the accumulator is (more or less) your final answer: you may need to do some final processing on it first, though.

In this case, you want to build up a pair of lists, and the starting point for building *any* list is an empty list.

```
dup :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
dup xs = dup' xs ([], [])
    where dup' :: [a] -> ([a], [a]) -> ([a], [a])
          dup' [] acc = ...
          dup' (x:xs) acc = ...
```

Think about what you want to do to a pair of lists in each case before you make the recursive call to `dup'`.

Note that the accumulator doesn't have to have the same type as the final return value, or even be a single argument. You could also define the tail-recursive version like

```
dup' :: [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
dup' [] accA accB = ...
dup' (x:xs) accA accB = ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`duh xs = (,) xs xs` is one such definition, lacking any non-tail calls in it.

`duh = dup` is another, because `dup` is already tail recursive, [*modulo `cons`*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tailrecursion-modulo-cons/info).

Comment: `dup = join (,)` is another handy idiom to remember.

Comment: An interesting quote from ["Tail Call"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) regarding tail recursion modulo cons: "But prefixing a value at the start of a list on exit from a recursive call is the same as appending this value at the end of the growing list on entry into the recursive call, thus building the list as a side effect, as if in an implicit accumulator parameter." I was going to draw this distinction in a more-explicit draft of my answer (before rejecting it as doing too much work for the OP).

Comment: @chepner [it so happens that...](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tail_call&diff=prev&oldid=458280080&diffmode=source) :) --- BTW I had `join (,)` there first, but replaced it after a minute's   thought, as too opaque for  the newbies.

Comment: Modulo cons? Why, in this case? There isn't any recursion at all.

Comment: @dfeuer that was referring to *`dup`*. the first one has no non-tail calls, consists only of a base case. we can always make it formally recursive by adding the non-firing clause, `duh xs = duh xs`. it's an exam question after all. :)

Comment: How is `dup` recursive?

Comment: `dup (x:xs) = let {(as, bs) = dup xs} in (x:as, x:bs)`...? it's in the question.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 2):

The archetypal tail recursive function is `foldl`. Write `dup` in terms of `foldl` and it will be tail recursive, at least after inlining `foldl`'s definition.